# window.print() not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have the following js code:

```
 window.print();
```

This works in Chrome and IE. It also works on iPhone safari. However, it does not work on Firefox.

The following does work in Firefox

```
alert()
window.print();
```

so I figure it's some kind of timing thing?  Note that my js code only loads after the page itself has been loaded:

```
 function loadJS() {     
      var element = document.createElement("script"); // 
      element.src = "url/js/all.js";
      document.body.appendChild(element);    
 }

if (window.addEventListener)
      window.addEventListener("load", loadJS, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", loadJS);
else 
   window.onload = loadJS;
```

Comment: have you checked...popups are blocked or not...???

Comment: where are you calling window.print(); ..?

Comment: It's called in my js code. It's NOT inside a onClick. The page loads, and then it's called.

Comment: If pop-ups were blocked then I don't see how it would work when I include the alert()

Comment: Can you show the whole *loadJS* function? `window.print()` works fine here, testing it in the dev console on **FF-23.0.1**.

Comment: I am agree with  Joe Simmons . It works for me as well in FF23.0.1.May be problem with loadJS.

Comment: Alright, I've included all the code.

Comment: It's so hard to tell without a good example. Is it possible for you to make a jsFiddle that reproduces your problem? Don't include your whole code, just try to write some example code similar to yours that shows it not working in Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Well, just making it wait, worked, although it seems silly to have to do it. 
Plus, I don't know if this will always work...

```
 setTimeout( 
    function() {
        window.print();
    }, 100);
```